# "Forwarding" attributes to directive templates

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a directive used like:

```
<div my-directive ng-disabled="moon.visible" />
```

Inside, it has a template like:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div><input ng-disabled="wat"><input ng-disabled="wat"></div>';
    };
});
```

I would like the inner inputs to be disabled as `moon.visible` changes.

Is it possible to define the template in such a way that it would just transparently forward the setting without an explicit `$watch`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like...

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: { disabled: '=ngDisabled' },
    template: '<input ng-disabled="disabled"/>'
  };
});
```

Comment: OK, that's one way. It works, but a two-way ngModel that I need for something else really doesn't seem to like isolated scope.

Comment: So what do you want to really realize?  May be you want to give us a usecase.

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for a way to transparently pass attributes to the template without an isolated scope or manual $watch. I'll leave it open for a while and accept your solution if none better appears.